# Blazor - passing arguments through Http.GetJsonAsync

Tags: c#, blazor

In index.cshtml @functions I am able to retrieve data from DB, while sending the argument chosenDate as shown under:

trackList = await Http.GetJsonAsync>("/api/Lopstat/Tracks/" + chosenDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

What if I want to send two arguments with my request? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send two arguments, you can define a class with two fields for these arguments. This class will automatically be JSON-encoded and sent as a string

You can use the SendJsonAsync method whose signature is displayed below:

```
  public static async Task<T> SendJsonAsync<T>(this HttpClient httpClient, HttpMethod method, string requestUri, object content)

// And this is how you can use it in your code...
trackList = await Http.SendJsonAsync<Change this to the return type>( HttpMethod.Get, "/api/Lopstat/Tracks", MyObject);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my first question on Stackoverflow! I will try out this solution.

Comment: I found that this works, but I had to change HttpMethod.Get to HttpMethod.Post